# 100% Height in dGrid

Tags: dojo, dgrid

How is it possible to make a dGrid instance take up 100% of the height of its container? I can use CSS to make the ".dgrid" classed div a specific height but when I set it to 100% it doesn't display.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Got it.

```
.dgrid {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: auto;
}
```

(With position absolute/relative on container, of course)

Comment: Some additional details: [_Dgrid Resizing within BorderContainer_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13427937/dgrid-resizing-within-bordercontainer/13436318#13436318) ;)

Answer (score 5):

I think the supported way to do this is with the [.dgrid-autoheight](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/4d1de1b2f5b3bcb93735eb793d7638700e413140/doc/migrating/API-Comparison.md#autoheight) css class.

```js
        require([
            "dgrid/List",
            "dgrid/OnDemandGrid",
            "dgrid/Selection",
            "dgrid/Keyboard",
            "dojo/_base/declare",
            "dgrid/test/data/createAsyncStore",
            "dgrid/test/data/smallColorData",
            "dojo/domReady!"
        ], function(List, Grid, Selection, Keyboard, declare, createAsyncStore, smallColorData){
                window.grid = new (declare([Grid, Selection, Keyboard]))({
                    className: "dgrid-autoheight",
                    collection: createAsyncStore({ data: smallColorData }),
                    columns: {
                        col1: "Color",
                        col5: "R",
                        col6: "G",
                        col7: "B"
                    }
                }, "grid");
            });
```

This is from the [test examples](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/4d1de1b2f5b3bcb93735eb793d7638700e413140/test/autoheight.html#L33).

Comment: dgrid-auroheight resize grid to content not to container

Answer (score 1):

@voidstate's answer is good.  Another way to do it is like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="containsDGrid">
    <div data-dojo-attach-point="dgrid"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.containsDGrid {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}

.dgrid {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The key is that if you set the height of the dgrid to 100%, the dgrid's parent must have its hight set.  For example if we don't set the height of the `.containsDGrid` div then it will look like this (notice the height of 2px):

[image]

For another example see [Dojo Dgrid - Use remaining space in block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24396814/dojo-dgrid-use-remaining-space-in-block/24396823#24396823)